# How to configure IIS/WCF to use wsat?

Tags: wcf, iis, certificate, weblogic, wsat

I would like do use Atomic Transactions between WCF and Weblogic, but I'm facing many problems to configure it.

I've already turned on the Wsat on Windows and associated it a valid certificate. I also enabled the SSL on IIS and configured the https port.

My main doubts are about the right WCF binding configurations and how and where I import the IIS certificate on Weblogic.

I imported my Wsat certificate in Demo.jks file (Weblogic keystore), but it did not work.

Best regards,

ps: Forgive my poor english :)